# Error while using Jparepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I was using JPA repository to get user data and store it in a list . Then is was going to iterate that list of users to get all the users. But there is an error in the forEach statement(Syntax error).

code:

```
package com.mohit.Services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.mohit.Repo.userrepo;
import com.mohit.beans.users;

public class loginuser {

  @Autowired
  userrepo Repo;

    public void loguser(users user){
      String pass =user.getPass();
      String uname =user.getName();
      List<users> userlist=Repo.findAll();

      forEach( users u : userlist){

      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `foreach` keyword in java, need to use `for`, so you have error in source code, please try below code for cycle, instead of your's:

```
for(users u : userlist){

}
```